# Ethernet device not managed on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, ethernet

I'm having problems to connect to internet using ethernet on arch linux.
I use NetworkManager and it tells me `Device not managed` for the Ethernet Network.

- This is the content of my `NetworkManager.conf`

  ```
  # Configuration file for NetworkManager.
  # See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.
  [ifupdown]
  managed=true
  ```
- and here is the status of the service

  ```
  systemctl status NetworkManager.service
  ● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
      Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service.d
               └─NetworkManager-ovs.conf
       Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-07-09 10:40:29 CEST; 8min ago
         Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
     Main PID: 26730 (NetworkManager)
        Tasks: 3 (limit: 18960)
       Memory: 11.0M
       CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
               └─26730 /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9395] dhcp4 (wlo1): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9395] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed unknown -> bound
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9407] device (wlo1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9420] device (wlo1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9422] device (wlo1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9425] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9444] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9445] policy: set 'RBIG02' (wlo1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
  Jul 09 10:40:31 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284031.9481] device (wlo1): Activation: successful, device activated.
  Jul 09 10:40:32 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284032.0036] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
  ```
- Also, I found this in my system log

  ```
  # journalctl -b | grep enp

  Jul 09 10:12:44 Anarchy systemd-udevd[666]: eth0: Failed to rename network interface 2 from 'eth0' to 'enp60s0': Device or resource busy
  ```

  ```
  # journalctl -b | grep eth

  Jul 09 10:12:42 Anarchy kernel: wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:05: WQBC data block query control method not found
  Jul 09 10:12:43 Anarchy kernel: r8169 0000:3c:00.0 eth0: RTL8168h/8111h, 8c:04:ba:a0:23:3e, XID 541, IRQ 164
  Jul 09 10:12:43 Anarchy kernel: r8169 0000:3c:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
  Jul 09 10:12:43 Anarchy kernel: r8169 0000:3c:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
  Jul 09 10:12:44 Anarchy systemd-udevd[635]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
  Jul 09 10:12:44 Anarchy systemd-udevd[666]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
  Jul 09 10:12:44 Anarchy systemd-udevd[666]: eth0: Failed to rename network interface 2 from 'eth0' to 'enp60s0': Device or resource busy
  Jul 09 10:12:44 Anarchy systemd-udevd[666]: eth0: Failed to process device, ignoring: Device or resource busy
  Jul 09 10:12:44 Anarchy systemd-udevd[668]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
  Jul 09 10:12:46 Anarchy NetworkManager[2918]: <info>  [1594282366.6504] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
  Jul 09 10:12:47 Anarchy NetworkManager[2918]: <info>  [1594282367.1419] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
  Jul 09 10:12:47 Anarchy kernel: r8169 0000:3c:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
  Jul 09 10:12:47 Anarchy kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
  Jul 09 10:12:53 Anarchy wpa_supplicant[3915]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=25
  Jul 09 10:12:53 Anarchy wpa_supplicant[3915]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 25 (PEAP) selected
  Jul 09 10:14:03 Anarchy sudo[5972]:   manuel : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/manuel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ip link set eth0 up
  Jul 09 10:28:11 Anarchy NetworkManager[18286]: <info>  [1594283291.6889] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
  Jul 09 10:28:11 Anarchy NetworkManager[18286]: <info>  [1594283291.6891] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
  Jul 09 10:33:21 Anarchy sudo[22070]:   manuel : TTY=pts/4 ; PWD=/home/manuel ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/dhcpd eth0
  Jul 09 10:33:22 Anarchy dhcpd[22072]: No subnet declaration for eth0 (no IPv4 addresses).
  Jul 09 10:33:22 Anarchy dhcpd[22072]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
  Jul 09 10:33:22 Anarchy dhcpd[22072]:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
  Jul 09 10:40:29 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284029.4918] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
  Jul 09 10:40:29 Anarchy NetworkManager[26730]: <info>  [1594284029.4920] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
  ```

The `/etc/network/interfaces` file does not exist on my machine, however I found suggestions that this is required to fix this problem (at least on ubuntu).

I'm not really familiar with this networking stuff, so I'd be happy for any suggestions on how to fix that.

EDIT:
I figure out that this does not happen when I boot the laptop without the power cord plugged in. However if I do that, I can't turn on my external graphics card (optimus-laptop) anymore, and I really don't see the connection between ethernet device, graphics card the power cord

Answer (score 1):

Check for a file `/etc/netctl/eth0` or similar inside `/etc/netctl`. If you need this NIC to be handled by NetworkManager, delete the file. Also `sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd` to disable external DHCP (it'll be handled by NetworkManager), reboot the system and then the NIC will be managed by NetworkManager. Else you can setup `eth0` by editing `/etc/netctl/eth0`, either using dchp or static IP.

Comment: There is no folder named `/etc/netctl/` on my system and the dhcpd service is disabled.
I'll try to get your seconds suggestion working though